# Approve and reject in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to give function to both approve and decline button that is in admin dashboard and display the result as remarks:pending/accepted/decline in user's dashboard.

here is my admin view

dashboard.php.blade

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th hidden>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Equipment</th>
    <th>Reservation Date</th>
    <th>Rooms</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach ($res as $resdata)
   <tr>
   <td hidden> </td>
   <td>{{$resdata->name}} </td>
   <td>{{$resdata->Name_item}}</td>
   <td>{{$resdata->dt_item}}</td>
   <td>{{$resdata->room_item}}  </td>
   <td>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Accept <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button></a>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline <i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
  </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

refer to this photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCMMv.png)

And when I click the accept button it will go to the accepted reservation table please refer here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQuqT.png)

Comment: What problem are you facing? SO is not a free coding service. You have to explain the problems you are facing. I think you are looking for ajax/fetch calls that hit an approve/reject endpoint when a user clicks the button

Comment: i already edit my post please check

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="{{route(YourRoute/{id})}}"
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Accept <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button></a>
</form>
```

In Your Controller

```
public function ($id){
  $reservation = Reservation::find($id);

  $reservation->status = true ;

  return redirect()->back()->with('message' , 'Success');
}

public function index (){
  $reservation = Reservation::where('status' , true);

  return view()->with('reservations' , $reservation);
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.